# Replacing a value in a comma separated list stored in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This would be 1 line of code in a normal programming language, but seems overly complex in SQL Server.

Given a table (yes no need to reply that comma separated values shouldn't be kept in columns):

```
| ID |  List        |
| 1  |  AB,ABC,ABCD |
```

What's the best way of replacing for example ONLY "AB" with "XX" and storing in back in the table?

Comment: all 'AB' or just the distinct value AB? and what version of sql server are you using? theres some nifty functions in the newer ones that could be used

Comment: ONLY 'AB'. SQL Server 2017

Comment: You think, that this *seems overly complex in SQL Server.*... Yet you don't want to be reminded of 1NF ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First append comas at the ends using `concat()`, so that each element is enclosed by commas. Then replace the element using `replace()` including the surrounding commas. Finally use `substring()` to get the string without the commas at the begin and end.

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET list = substring(replace(concat(',', list, ','), ',AB,', ',XX,'), 2, len(replace(concat(',', list, ','), ',AB,', ',XX,')) - 2);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3fcf4fe98c1e60f482074d85e6cdeaf3)

Comment: This is ugly, but very efficient, +1 from my side ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Bit hacky and a mess and assuming your on a version that can use string_split, this will work:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, List VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1, 'AB,ABC,ABCD')


SELECT  ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(IIF(value = 'AB', 'XX', value) AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @TABLE 
         CROSS APPLY string_split (List,',')
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM @TABLE t
```

returns:

```
ID  List_Output
1    XX, ABC, ABCD
```

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but this approach does not guarantee, to re-create the list in the same sorting (well, I've never encountered any problems, but there might be cases...). Furthermore you are adding a blank with the comma, but this is easy to resolve...